# Localhost - 404 Not Found

Tags: php, apache, laravel-valet

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2017 with macOS High Sierra. I use apache for my local development environment; however, for a couple of weeks I could not manage to access my localhost.

When I navigate to localhost, only thing appears on the screen is a

```
404 - Not Found
```

I tried:

```
apachectl configtest
```

and get an

```
Syntax OK
```

Interesting thing about the localhost, in the title it writes

```
Valet - Not Found
```

which makes me think the problem might because of Laravel's valet.

Also here is my /etc/apache2/users/username.conf file

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Order allow, deny
</Directory>
```

And my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file
https://hastebin.com/ogagobocek.apache

I really need your help since my development has stopped because of this error.

Comment: How did u add laravel valet to your project ?

Comment: As far as I remember I used valet park but the interesting thing is valet should not be active in this directory. It is active in another path and I checked it using valet paths

Comment: have you tried using php built-in server ? check if it works. go to your project folder `/public` and run this command : `php -S localhost:80`. make sure to stop apache